# Find a word in a line no matter how it's written

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a word in a simple string no matter how it's written. For example:

'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem.'

Let's say I search for 'lorem' written in lowercase and I'd like to replace both 'lorem' and 'Lorem' with 'example'.
The thing is, I want to search and replace the word no matter how it's written.

I think this should be done using regex but I'm not very familiar with it. Maybe you guys can help.

Comment: a regular expression in combination with the `sub()` function and the `i` modifier might do that.

Comment: If you don't want to use regex, you can do `'lorem' in my_str.lower()` (or `'LOREM' in my_str.upper()`)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem."
search_key = "Lorem"
print(re.sub(r'%s' % search_key.lower(), 'example', sentence.lower()))
>>> example ipsum dolor sit amet example.
```

Comment: There is no need to use regex here if you are going to do the lowering yourself (and not use things like word boundaries).

Comment: This does make you lose info about capitalization for the not-to-be-replaced words though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the letters upper or lower case. I made lower case for this time.

```
import re

x='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem.'.lower()
y=input(" What word do you want to chage?").lower()


if not y in x:
    print("This word is not in the sentence. You cannot change it!")
else:
    z= y + " which word you want to write instead?"
    z=input(z)
    t=re.sub(y,z,x)
    print(t)
```

Comment: There is no need to use regex here if you are going to do the lowering yourself (and not use things like word boundaries).

Comment: I just used regex to replace the word

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you.

```
import re
pattern_rep = re.compile(re.escape('lorem'), re.IGNORECASE)
new_pattern=pattern_rep.sub('example', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem')
print(new_pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without `regex` (works for your example in the question):

```
s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem.'
print(s.replace('lorem', 'example').replace('Lorem', 'example'))
# example ipsum dolor sit amet example.
```